# error ORA-02291 APEX_220200.WWV_FLOW_NAV_LIST_FK on installation of Oracle APEX application using apex_application_install and sqlplus

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, sqlplus

After exporting an apex application using separated files mode available on apex web console,
I tried to import it into another workspace using sqlplus with the following command

```html
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Apr 28 10:36:04 2023
Version 19.18.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Fri Apr 28 2023 10:35:33 -03:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.17.0.0.0

SQL> declare
  2      l_workspace_id number;
  3      n_exists_app number(1);
  4      n_application_id number;
  5  begin
  6      select workspace_id into l_workspace_id
  7        from apex_workspaces
  8       where workspace = USER||'_WS';
  9
 10      apex_application_install.set_workspace_id( l_workspace_id );
 11      APEX_APPLICATION_INSTALL.GENERATE_APPLICATION_ID;
 12      APEX_APPLICATION_INSTALL.GENERATE_OFFSET;
 13      apex_application_install.set_schema( USER );
 14      apex_application_install.set_application_alias( USER||'_APP' );
 15      APEX_APPLICATION_INSTALL.SET_APPLICATION_NAME(p_application_name  => USER||'_APP');
 16  end;
 17  /
```

at the end of installation, during execution of script end_environment.sql, the following error occurrs

```html
--application/end_environment
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02091: transaction rolled back
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (APEX_220200.WWV_FLOW_NAV_LIST_FK) violated -
parent key not found
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220200.WWV_FLOW_SECURITY", line 1999
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220200.WWV_FLOW_IMP", line 1104
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220200.WWV_FLOW_IMP", line 1130
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220200.WWV_FLOW_IMP", line 1168
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

What could be causing this error?

p.s. Apex version: 22.2.0